# Export enum from library and use that in consumer typescript project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums

I am creating a library from where I am exporting a React component alongwith some interfaces and an enum.
I compiled typescript project. Its because the library is a for React and not typescript. I am creating proper definition files also.

Now on my consumer project, I am doing this:

```
import { IMyComponentProps, MyComponent } from "mycomp-lib";
```

As you can see I am able to use `IMyComponentProps`. I am using this for a function which will do some calculations and return props for `MyComponent`.

But from my library I am also exporting an enum which is this:

```
export const enum DirectionEnum {
  UP,
  DOWN,
  RIGHT,
  LEFT
}
```

But when I do `import { IMyComponentProps, MyComponent, DirectionEnum } from "mycomp-lib";`

I start getting error that `DirectionEnum` is not exported from `mycomp-lib`.

This enum is needed as it can be useful even if the consumer of `mycomp-lib` is written in plain javascript. But in the typescript project, it's definitely needed.

I am using typescript v3 and React v16.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh I got it.

Typescript doesn't create lookup table for `const enum`, it creates lookup table only for `enum`.
But because of this the perf of `const enum` is better.

For consumer typescript project a lookup table can be created by providing option `preserveConstEnums: true` in tsconfig.json.

This will still not let my library to evaluate value from a lookup table (perf benefit), but it will export that lookup table to consumer(which I wanted).

Thanks to all those who thought about this question, I hope this will help others too.